# ls: cannot access file : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, ls

In the shell script, I will have to access the binary logs stored in /usr/local/mysql/data.
but when I do this,

```
STARTLOG=000002
ENDLOG=000222
file=`ls -d /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.{$STARTLOG..$ENDLOG}| sed 's/^.*\///'`
echo $file
```

I get the below error :

```
ls: cannot access /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.{000002..000222}: No such file or directory.
```

But when I manually enter the numbers in the range the shell scripts runs normally without error.

Comment: Do you really have a file `mysql-bin.{000002..000222}` ? I think no.

Comment: How do you launch script? It seems you are launching it via sh, not bash|zsh

Comment: I launched it with bash, but still it gives me same error.

Comment: I'm able to get those files when I enter the number directly within the braces, but not getting the files when I enter with a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `seq(1)`:

```
file=`ls -d $(seq --format="/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.%06.0f" $STARTLOG $ENDLOG) | sed 's/^.*\///'`
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, brace expansion occurs before variables are expanded. This means that you can not use variable inside of `{}` and get your expected results. I recommend using an array and a for loop:

```
startlog=2
endlog=222
files=()

for (( i=startlog; i<=endlog; i++ ));
   fname=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.$(printf '%06d' $i)
   [[ -e "$fname" ]] && files+=("${fname##*/}")
done

printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the files in the range 000002..000222

but because of the quotes you are asking for the file with the name

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.{000002..000222}
```

I would use a shell loop: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Comment: Yes I want access for all files in the range.

Comment: No, it is due to using variables. `bash` rules are rather ad-hoc.

Comment: There are bugs in the linked guide.